# Creating a new item in an existing SharePoint list using rest dynamically without hard coding the field name?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a new list item in a SharePoint list using REST API. 
I am hardcoding the field names I want to pass them through an array. 
The array will be updated through another function. 
I am trying to reuse the normal code but I hit a roadblock. 
This code is not running at all, the metadata second value where I am trying to loop around the array and add the each element of an array value. Each element inside the array is my field name.

```html
var favorite=[];
   //favorite is an array of fields title list is updated dynamically with another function
   //I want to dynamically add that dynamically when I create a new list item

var item = {"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.TestCatalogListItem"},for(int i=0; i<favourite.length;i++){favorite[i]:cells[i]}};

_createListItem(item);

function _createListItem( listItems,listname, success, failure) {
   $.ajax({
   url: "https://site/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('MYLIST')/items",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
   data: JSON.stringify(listItems),
   headers: {
   "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
   "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
   },
   success: function (data) {
   //success(data);
   },
   error: function (data) {
   //failure(data);
   }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the for loop into the _createListItem function.

I haven't used the ajax method before, I have just used the JSOM and built in SP functions, but for me I pass in an object with up to 7 keys: *listName*, *folderName*, *fields*, *successFunctionCallback*, *succesFunctionParams*, *failedFunctionCallback*, and *failedFunctionParams*. The fields value is just an array of field names and value like you have. Inside the create function I loop over the fields and set the specific value. For you, you'd just be doing the same thing but building a *data* variable.